# How does one 'override' string used in a core file?

Tags: 7

I'm trying to change the text "Already a member?" located in commons_core.blocks.inc to a different value. I would preferrably like to override this value and not directly edit a file in /profiles/drupal_commons/.

Can anyone recommend a good solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you are referring is used on line 167 of the commons_core.block.inc file, that is part of `_commons_core_header_login_block_view()`, and which is included in the following control statement.

```
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    // Only provide a link
    $block['content'] = t('Already a member? !login', array('!login' => l(t('Login'), 'user')));
  }
```

You can use the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module as suggested by Clive. The help provided from the module says:

> To replace a string, enter **the complete string** that is passed through the [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t) function. String Overrides cannot translate user-defined content; it can only replace strings wrapped in the `t()` function. To find the strings you can actually change, open up a module and look for `t()` function calls. Places where %, @, or ! are used means that the translation contains dynamic information (such as the node type or title in the above examples); these are not translated while the text around them is.

In your case, you need to use the string "Already a member? !login" because that is the string passed to `t()`, not the string containing the login link as replaced by `t()`.

You can also change the code in the settings.php file as suggested by md2. In this case, the code that you need to add to the file is the following one.

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'] = array(
  'Already a member? !login' => 'YOUR STRING',
);
```

Replace `'YOUR STRING'` with the string you want to use.

What of the two methods you should use depends from how many strings you need to replace. If you have a single string to replace, then you could use the settings.php method, especially if there is just a limited number of users that would need to alter that string, and those users are comfortable doing it without using the user interface offered by Drupal, but through FTP, or SSH. In the case you are going to use the settings.php method, you could write your customizations in a different file that is then included from settings.php; in this way:

- You can use the same settings for different domains/sub-domains, without to even copy that part in different settings.php files.
- You can control who has the permission to write the settings.php file, which contains the most sensitive information, without to be so restrictive on who can change the other settings available on settings.php.

If vice-versa, you need to change more than one string, your site is using more than two languages (which could be possibly increased on the near future), or your need that more than two users can alter the strings, without to give them FTP, or SSH access, then you should use the String Overrides module.

Both the methods replaces any occurrence of the string with the one you supply. It is not possible to replace the string only in specific pages, or in a specific block, using these methods; if there is another module that uses the same string, the string will be replaced with the string you set.

As the string is not used from a theme function (which could be overridden with your own theme function), the alternative to the methods I reported here would be to implement a block in your custom module, which is used to replace the block already implemented in Drupal Commons, and which uses the string you want to use.
In Drupal 7 would be easier, as it allows a module to implement [hook_block_view_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7), or [hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7) to alter how the block implemented from another module is rendered.

Comment: Is settings.php a "safe" area to modify? That is, when update time comes, is settings.php ever overwritten?

Comment: No, settings.php is never overwritten, for a simple reason: It contains the information necessary to access the database used from Drupal. Drupal comes with default.settings.php, and as far as I recall, I have never had to copy the content of default.settings.php over settings.php, apart when I install Drupal on a new site.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to confirm. There won't be many changes but I didn't want to muck around core files.

Comment: The settings.php file is not considered a core file; core files are the one included in the includes, misc, modules, profiles, and themes directories, or the .php files in the Drupal root directory. The settings.php file is a file that is created from the user who installs Drupal on a new site.

Answer (score 5):

For overriding a few text strings the easiest way is probably to use the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module:

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.

**UPDATE**

The line that sets this particular string is:

```
$block['content'] = t('Already a member? !login', array('!login' => l(t('Login'), 'user')));
```

Once it's built up, the string will actually look something like this:

```
'Already a member? <a href="/user">Login</a>'
```

That's why you're having difficulty targeting it with the string overrides module at the moment. If you're not developing a multilingual site you might just get away with inspecting the `<a>` tag in the block, and using that HTML in string overrides. I'm pretty sure it'll work.

Comment: And we have this and in other places it appears to take. However, string replace does not seem to act on this piece of login text. I'm baffled.

Comment: @Richard Seems there's a little more to it, I've updated the answer

Comment: Yes, that is the exact position of the text I want to replace. And I've tried various iterations of "Already a member?". Nothing seems to hold. I'm able to change the login phrase to something else. Could I override this value using a hook function in a module?

Comment: There's no `hook_block_alter()` in Drupal 6 so I think the easiest way would be to implement your own block using `hook_block()`, and copy the code for the block out of the commons_core.block.inc file, changing what you need as you go. Then you can use your new block in place of the default commons one

Answer (score 2):

If you edit the settings.php file for your site and scroll down to near the end you'll find the following if your site is Drupal 6:

```
# $conf['locale_custom_strings_en'] = array(
#   'forum'      => 'Discussion board',
#   '@count min' => '@count minutes',
# );
```

The settings.php file for Drupal 7 contains the following instead (note values are nested within an additional array):

```
# $conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
#   'forum'      => 'Discussion board',
#   '@count min' => '@count minutes',
# );
```

If you are simply doing a single replace and not translating many many strings I would say this is the way to go.

~Mark